# Página de sinônimos de tag ainda não traduzida

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

A página de exemplo ainda não foi traduzida:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/entity-framework/synonyms

Sugestão:

> Sinônimos da Tag para entity-framework
>
> Perguntas incorretamente marcados são difíceis de encontrar e resposta. Se você souber de grafias alternativas comuns ou siglas para esta tag, adicione-os aqui para que possamos corrigi-las automaticamente no futuro. Por exemplo, sugerir "biciclo" como sinônimo de bicicleta, ou "meia" para meias.
>
> entity-framework atualmente não possui sinônimos aprovados.
>
> veja todos os sinônimos da tag »
>
> Usuários com mais de 1.250 reputação e uma pontuação de resposta total de 5 ou mais na tag pode sugerir sinônimos da tag. Os usuários com uma pontuação total de resposta (votos a favor menos votos contra) de 5 ou mais na tag podem votar para sinônimos de tag. Sugestões serão aprovadas automaticamente quando atingem uma pontuação de 4, e excluídas automaticamente quando atingem uma pontuação de -2.
>
> Sugira um sinônimo para entity-framework: [] <kbd>Sugerir</kbd>

Comment: Que coisa estranha, até pouco tempo estava traduzida, destraduziram recentemente. Veja o print na minha pergunta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1164/3117

Comment: Teve um outro caso de destradução que eu vi recentemente que foi na medalha Estudante, mas já consertaram, tem alguma coisa destraduzindo tudo por aí, rsrs.. Alguém deveria investigar.

Comment: Bizarro. Também lembro de já ter visto essa página traduzida em algum momento.

Comment: Tô falando que tem alguma coisa destraduzindo tudo por aí! Acabou de aparecer `Looks OK` ao invés de `Parece boa` na fila de análise de publicações de baixa qualidade.

Comment: Tá com cara que toda vez que muda o texto em inglês some a tradução aqui. Devem ter usado o texto como chave no dicionário.

Answer (score 2):

Esse e outros erros de tradução estão ocorrendo por conta de alterações no texto original em Inglês, que acaba avacalhando o sitema de localização do site.

Infelizmente **eu** não posso adicionar novas chaves de tradução, ou alterar o sistema diretamente. Então pedi à equipe de desenvolvimento que:

1. Atualize as chaves de tradução, inserindo os novos textos em Inglês, para que eu possa então traduzir.
2. Pense numa forma de evitar que isso tenha que ser feito toda vez que ocorrer uma mudança de texto.

Como boa parte da equipe se encontra viajando ou focada na mudança de data centers, só vamos ter alguma resposta sobre isso no meio da semana que vem.